# With reverse proxy match exactl url string including parameters and redirect

Tags: reverse-proxy

I have a series of url:

```
http://ip:port/path/page.php?paramN=foo
http://ip:port/path/page.php?paramN=bar?paramy=whatever
```

...
and so on

I need to match the url "as is" and redirect for example the first one to:

```
http://host1/john.php
```

The second one to:

```
http://host2/doe.php
```

and so on

No regular expressions no rewrite just a thing like an hashmap.

How can I do with a reverse proxy like apache or nginx?

Thanks,
Mario

Comment: You want redirect for whole URL or for paramN?

Comment: I guess you meant `http://ip:port/path/page.php?paramN=bar&paramy=whatever` in your example URL.

Answer (score 1):

In Apache, if you only need to redirect exact match without regular expressions, you can use [mod_alias `Redirect`s](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) and add them in a [`<Proxy>` container](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxy) before your `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse`.

```
<Proxy *>
  Redirect /path/page.php?paramN=foo http://host1/john.php
  Redirect /path/page.php?paramN=bar&paramy=whatever http://host2/doe.php
</Proxy>

ProxyPass / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
ProxyPassReverse / http://127.0.0.1:8080/
```

In this example the `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` is made up as you didn't specify what you have there. It's just there for showing the correct order of the directives.

Comment: nginx `location` paths match only normalized URIs, which do not contain query arguments. Therefore your nginx approach won't work.

Comment: Thanks, Tero. I removed the Nginx part – someone else having currently more time can help with that.